# Why "Invalid date format"?

Tags: dart

I cannot understand why the date format is invalid
I format the date as I want to display it in my field

```
_dr = formatDate(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(Tools.birthDate),
    [dd, '.', mm, '.', yyyy]);

_birthDateController = new TextEditingController(text: _dr);
```

Trying to convert it to Date

```
 _dateTime = DateTime.parse(_birthDateController.text);
```

Comment: and what's value of _birthDateController.text? values of dd, mm, yyyy

Comment: @Autocrab yes, dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: use instead dd.MM.yyyy

Comment: @Autocrab  it don't work =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your shared code what `formatDate` method is doing behind the scenes. However, for effectively parsing and formatting the date and time, you can use the `DateFormat` class that is part of the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

Sample code:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  final date = DateTime.now();

  final dateFormat = 'dd.MM.yyyy';
  final formattedDate = DateFormat(dateFormat).format(date);
  print('formatted date: $formattedDate');

  final parseFormattedDate = DateFormat(dateFormat).parse(formattedDate).toIso8601String();
  print('parse formatted date: $parseFormattedDate');
}
```

Output:

```
formatted date: 18.09.2020
parse formatted_date: 2020-09-18T00:00:00.000
```

for a list of available date and time formats see the [documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/src/intl/date_format.dart) for the `DateFormat` class